# Local transparent Squid under Windows and redirecting local traffic to it

Tags: windows, proxy, localhost, squid, transparentproxy

Good evening. 
I want to set a local transparent proxy on my machine, using Squid, for learning/caching/traffic controlling/blocking purposes - most for learning.

The problem is, I'm running Windows, and I don't know how to forcefully redirect all the traffic to the proxy like one would do with iptables in a Linux environment.

I want to do it transparently in order to leave absolutely no path to reach the internet other than the proxy. Also, I specifically want to achieve this using Windows AND this single machine, though.

I've so far been unable to find a way to do this, and after a few weeks of not getting anywhere, I've decided to ask about it here.

How can I set up a local transparent proxy using Squid in a Windows machine AND redirect this same machine's traffic to the proxy, like when using iptables in Linux? 
Additionally, is it possible to force traffic originating from other kinds of software through the proxy in this fashion, such as online games, messaging software, etc?

Thank you very much in advance!

-Lara K.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Windows Squid build main page ( http://squid.acmeconsulting.it ) at the bottom, you will find that transparent proxy mode is not available on Windows.